# Chatter and communities

Tags: chatter, community

I am absolutely new at Salesforce.

Can anybody explain what is the difference between Salesforce communities and salesforce Chatter (if any)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chatter and Salesforce Community are two very different things. Chatter is for messaging while Salesforce Community is like a portal. Chatter is available inside of a Salesforce community.

---

According to Salesforce, [Chatter](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/gettingstarted/whatischatter/) is:

> Chatter is a brand-new way to collaborate at work. Because status
>   information about people and important projects is automatically
>   pushed to you, Chatter makes it easy to connect with the people and
>   information you care about most.

When thinking about [Chatter](https://www.salesforce.com/chatter/overview/), try to picture it as a replacement of email, instant messenger, and a bulletin board all at once. Your users can communicate with each other in groups, on their personal feed, on feeds on specific objects, over instant messenger, or even direct message.

---

According to Salesforce, [Salesforce Community](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/communities/faq/) is:

> Salesforce Communities is an online platform that enables rich
>   collaboration between employees, customers, partners, suppliers and
>   distributors. Organizations can create fully-branded public or private
>   communities that connect members directly with each other – and with
>   relevant content, data and business processes. Salesforce Communities
>   is the only community platform that combines the power of social with
>   mobile participation, trusted security, and direct connection to
>   business processes.

When thinking about [Salesforce Community](http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/communities/), think about a portal. Salesforce Community is a way for your customers or partners to directly interact within your Salesforce organization. It has Chatter enabled, so your Community users can utilize that functionality.